# How to delete item in list whilst iterating through list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops

I have a list of words, and a function that searches for a word by its length and the letters inside the word.

The for loop at the end cycles through the list of possible words (generated by the given length), and it should either print the word if it contains the given letter, or delete the word from the list of possible words if it does not contain the given letter.

How can I achieve this here:

```
wlist = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Cherry', 'Donkey']

def wordSearch(wlist):
    posWords = []
    length = int(input('Enter length of word: '))
    print("POSSIBLE WORD(S):")
    for word in wlist:
        stripWord = word.replace(' ', '')
        if len(stripWord) == length:
            print("%s (%s)" % (word, length))
            posWords.append(word)

    while True:
        searchOptions = ['Add Known Letter', 'Exit']
        searchIndex, item = chooseFromMenu(searchOptions)
        if searchIndex == 0:
            letter = input('Enter letter: ')
            print("POSSIBLE WORD(S):")
            for word in posWords:
                if letter in word:
                    print(word)
                else:
                    # remove word from list somehow
        else:
            break
```

Specifically this block:

```
letter = input('Enter letter: ')
print("POSSIBLE WORD(S):")
for word in posWords:
    if letter in word:
        print(word)
    else:
        # remove word from list somehow
```

I've tried to do `del word` and `posWords.pop(word)` but neither seem to work.

I also tried `.remove()` but I cant exactly remember what I did with that.

I'll go into more detail with the problem I'm having here...

If I type in the letter 'e', it should remove 'Banana' from the list of possible words so that when I type 'n' I should only get 'Donkey', not 'Donkey' and 'Banana'.

If that makes sense.

I have just tried `posWords.remove(word)` and it hasn't done this either...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Comment: Unfortunately not. I saw that post before I decided to write my own. Solutions didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Why don't those solutions work?

Comment: Why do you have to remove them while iterating? Do it in two steps: Print all the matching words, then remove all the non-matching words.

Comment: The answer to _"How to delete item in list whilst iterating through list?"_ is **no**. Think of a different way to accomplish your goals.

Comment: @zvone if you're saying it's not possible then fair enough. Just thought there must be a way to do it. (without making separate lists etc)

Comment: Yes, there is a way to do it without additional lists, but not while iterating through this list. You could e.g. increment list index in a loop and modify the list while doing that. A similar solution exists in the linked question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over the list in reverse, so that removing an element doesn't affect the rest of the iteration.

```
for i in range(len(posWords)-1, -1, -1):
    if letter in posWords[i]:
        print(posWords[i])
    else:
        posWords.pop(i)
```

This is the solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1207485/1491895) to the question you said didn't solve your problem.

Note that the argument to `pop()` is the list index, not a list element.

Comment: Maybe we should combine our answers, as they point to the two ways of iterating in both directions

Comment: They're different enough

Answer (score 1):

You can use a while loop and only increase the iterator, if no item is removed.

```
i = 0
while i < len(posWords):
    if letter in word:
        print(word)
        i += 1
    else:
        del posWords[i] # posWords.pop(i) does the same
```

This works, because if an item is removed, the next items index is reduced by 1 so i now points to the next item

Comment: This is the same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/42773232/1491895 in the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question properly then the following should work:

```
letter = input('Enter letter: ')
print("POSSIBLE WORD(S):")
for word in posWords[:]:
    if letter in word:
        print(word)
    else:
        posWords.remove(word)
```

Comment: The last line should be `posWords.remove(word)`